# How can i convert the list into three lists based on criteria and put in dictionary

Tags: python, list

I have the list like this

```
mylist = [student_number , student_age , student_marks , subject_name , subject_marks, subject_date , ass_name , ass_number]
```

i want something like

```
   list_student = [student_number , student_age , student_marks]
   list_subject = [subject_name , subject_marks, subject_date]
   list_ass     = [ass_name , ass_number]
```

so that it matches the text before underscore put that as key to dictionary

I want to convert that to a dictonary so that i can access something like

```
 for a AllList['student']:
           Student stuff
```

EDIT: The list elements can be in any order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```python
# Build dictionary with prefix:list pairs
targets = {
    'student_': [],
    'subject_': [],
    'ass_': []
}

for i in mylist:
    # Try to find matching prefix
    for prefix in targets:
        if i.startswith(prefix):
            targets[prefix].append(i)
            break
```

This will easily allow you to add many more prefixes and doesn't care about the order.

Assuming (that the values are strings):

```python
mylist = ['student_number', 'student_age', 'student_marks', 'subject_name',
          'subject_marks', 'subject_date' , 'ass_name' , 'ass_number' ]
```

You'll get result like this:

```python
>>> for i in targets: print( i, targets[i])
...
ass_ ['ass_name', 'ass_number']
student_ ['student_number', 'student_age', 'student_marks']
subject_ ['subject_name', 'subject_marks', 'subject_date']
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = ['student_number', 'student_age', 'student_marks', 'subject_name',
      'subject_marks', 'subject_date' , 'ass_name' , 'ass_number' ]


d = defaultdict(list)
for v in myList:
    k = v.split('_')[0]
    d[k].append(v)
```

It will give you:

```
>>>print d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'ass': ['ass_name', 'ass_number'], 'student': ['student_number', 'student_age', 'student_marks'], 'subject': ['subject_name', 'subject_marks', 'subject_date']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
>>> mylist = ['student_number', 'student_age', 'student_marks', 'subject_name',
...           'subject_marks', 'subject_date' , 'ass_name' , 'ass_number' ]
>>> import itertools
>>> m = {k:list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(mylist, lambda s: s.split('_')[0])}
>>> m
{'ass': ['ass_name', 'ass_number'], 'student': ['student_number', 'student_age', 'student_marks'], '
subject': ['subject_name', 'subject_marks', 'subject_date']}
```